# Launch google map from mobile Browser

Tags: dictionary, mobile-website

I was using "google local" on NOKIA 6800 browser 
the search result page had a link "view on map?"
Clicking on it launched Google Maps application, and map centered on the location
of the search result.

how it is done?? Javascript ?? I have seen similar behavior in Iphone

Answer (score 3):

For a static map you can use:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=kerstendalseweg%2017,berg%20en%20dal,%20nederland&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false
```

Wrapped in an anchor for use in a HTML page:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=kerstendalseweg%2017,berg%20en%20dal,%20nederland&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false">Go to Vette BSO</a>
```

For starting navigation I used this (with start en destination address)

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=kerstendalseweg 17, berg en dal, nederland&daddr=51.8285781,5.9287059">Go to Vette BSO</a>
```

From [google maps API docs](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/maps/faq.html):
You can also easily link to Google Maps for driving directions. We suggest you use the following format for driving directions on Google Maps:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr={start_address}&daddr={destination_address}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what mobile you use.

On Android you can use either `http://maps.google.com/maps?` prefix or `geo:lat,long?` prefix in url.
[Invoking Google Applications on Android Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)

On Iphone you can use `comgooglemaps://?` prefix:
[Google Maps iOS URL Scheme](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme)

To detect mobile device type use the following java script (this one detects iPhone or iPad):

```
if ((userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1) )
    window.location = "comgooglemaps://?saddr=london&daddr=manchester"
```